# Как сделать так, чтобы JavaScript работал с 2 classid?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы JavaScript работал с 2 classid?
Есть `.dropbtn` и у меня ещё есть один класс `.dropbtn1`. Я бы хотел чтобы меню виводило и там и там при нажатии(причем одно и то же меню).

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: я не вчитываля, но похоже, что нужно просто заюзать closest, но вообще не ясно, зачем вы два разных класса используете, используйте один

Comment: `.classNameOne.classNameTwo`?

Comment: У меня в мобильной версии кнопка выглядит по другому, и вообще не в том <div> блоке, но хочу чтобы при нажатии открывалась моя менюшка.